# Print CCK field "A" if CCK field "B" has a value of "Z"

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I want to print a CCK field (we'll call it CCK field "A") only if the value of another CCK field (we'll call it CCK field "B") matches a string. CCK field "B" is a select-list field with two options: "red" and "blue". I'd like to display the value of CCK field "A" only if the value of CCK field "B" is "blue". If the value is "red", then CCK field "A" should not be displayed at all.

How can I do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THIMK! Test the value of Field B before printing Field A.

```
<?php 
if(isset($node->field_field_b['und'][0]['value']) && ($node->field_field_b['und'][0]['value'] == 'blue')) { 
    if(isset($node->field_field_a['und'][0]['value'])) {
          print $node->field_field_a['und'][0]['value'];
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Great. Happy to help.